# Can I conduct Kolmogorov-Smirnov test on censored data?

Tags: kolmogorov-smirnov-test, censoring, kaplan-meier

Normally, Kolmogorov-Smirnov is conducted on full, uncensored data with test statistics.

$$
sup_x |F(x)-F^*(x)|
$$

Or equivalently,

$$
sup_x|S(x)-S^*(x)|
$$

,where $F(x)$,$S(x)$ is proposed function's CDF and survival function and $F^*(x)$ and $S^*(x)$ are empirical estimation on CDF and Survival function.

This makes me wonder can I generalized it to censored data? Again, using

$$
sup_x|S(x)-S^*(x)|
$$

but now $S^*(x)$ is Kaplan Meier Estimator.

Is it appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

The distribution of $\sup_x|S(x)-\hat S(x)|$ under censoring is not the same as without censoring, and it depends on the censoring distribution. So it's not possible either to use the K-S test as it is or to come up with a new reference distribution that works for all censored data.

If you know the censoring mechanism (eg, you know that it's censoring at iid censoring times, or that it's censoring after the 50th failure, or whatever) you can use simulation.

Simulate data from your proposed distribution $S$, censor it using the observed censoring distribution, compute the test statistic, and repeat many times to get a simulation-based reference distribution.